# check whether angularjs $interval is active/running

Tags: javascript, angularjs, setinterval

Is there a way to check whether an angularjs $interval is running/active (i.e. not cancelled)
e.g.

```
var foo = $interval(function() {},1000)
...
// need to do something like
// if (foo.isActive)...
```

Of course, it's possible to store that as state in a variable and change it wherever $interval.cancel() or $interval() gets called, but it would be less bug prone not to do so.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

Comment: How do you want to check it? create output element that displays the state?

Comment: There is no way to check without having the hooks to announce starting and stopping of the interval.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

Comment: thanks for finding the other question, and marking this as a duplicate. Please could you change the title of the other question? The content is very good, and accurately answers the question that I asked, but the title is not accurate, and might cause someone to overlook it (as I did)

Comment: @tom Done. But somehow it popped up on top when i searched for decorating interval... ;)

Comment: @PSL thanks - that's much better.